# Запятая да/нет: "Выборы, и с чем их едят"

Tags: пунктуация

Очень прошу пояснить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна, т.к. здесь две грамматические основы.

Comment: Спасибо! :)

Answer (score 2):

"Выборы, и с чем их едят". Можно считать, что первое предложение назывное. Вторая часть  - это устойчивое выражение, используется разные варианты оформления, например:

Монтессори: что это такое и с чем его едят?

Йод, и с чем его едят.

Пусть они приедут и разберутся сами, что это за зверь и с чем его едят.

Answer (score 2):

Неделимая синтаксическая единица "с чем их едят" (по форме - неопределённо-личное предложение), в данном случае является подлежащим и имеет значение "их суть". Ср.: ***Выборы и их суть.***  Если в состав сложносочинённого предложения входят номинативные предложения, то запятая перед И не ставится. Думаю, что и в предложенном случае запятая не нужна.

Другой вариант оформления:
***Выборы: с чем их едят.*** Правда, смысл предложения несколько меняется, акцент смещается на вторую часть.  Лексическая несочетаемость, впрочем, во всех вариантах предложения явная.

Comment: Вы считаете, что это номинативное предложение? Номинативное предложение обычно сообщает факт существования, бытия,а здесь я не вижу подобный информации. На мой взгляд, здесь скорее именительный темы с последующем раскрытием темы. Выборы, и с чем их едят.Или. как вы указали: Выборы: с чем их едят.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматика фразы несколько сомнительная, а правила распространяются только на корректные фразы. В остальных случаях - фантазия автора. И чем дальше от корректной грамматики, тем больше этой фантазии. Я бы поставил тире.

Насчет двух основ крепко сомневаюсь. Разве тут не два однородных "подлежащих"?
Первое - "выборы", второе - "с чем их едят"?

Comment: Первое подлежащее, второе -  неопределенно личное предложение. Что вас не устроило в грамматике? Такие предложения часто встречаются в СМИ. См. Справочник-практикум.Д.Э. Розенталь. Знаки препинания в газетных и журнальных заголовках. Стр.320.

Comment: То, что не совершенно воспринимается второе как неопределенно-личное.  
Как именительный темы - да. Вот в таком оформлении, понятнее?
***«"Выборы" и "С чем их едят"­­»***.

А какие еще примеры встречаются? "Что это за зверушки(,) и с чем их едят"? Так я и тут не уверен в обязательности запятой.

Comment: Подлежащее - " выборы" и есть именительный темы.

Comment: В вашем предложении ''Выборы" и "С чем их едят" два не связанных друг с другом предложения. Союз "и" здесь объединяет два самостоятельных предложения.

Comment: Необходимость запятой следует из наличия паузы, которая характерна для предложений с разноструктурными частями.